# Qt Position offset Surface tablet

Tags: qt

I have a program I designed for Desktop Applications for Windows with Qt MinGW 5.7. I was curious to see if it would work on a Surface tablet with Win10.

It does work, except for a small detail: eveything is offset. For instance, I grab the screen width with
"GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)" and I use this to place my window in the center of the screen. This works well on WinXp to Win10. However on a Surface tablet with Win10, everything is offset.
If I place an object at (0,0) it's fine but if I place it at (10,0), it will appear at (20,0).
What can I do ?

Thank you so much,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

For the offset problem, I think it has to do with High-DPI scaling: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html
But i'm not sure what to do to do it right.

Thanks,

Alex